# Ethernet NIC seems to stop FTP traffic

Tags: networking, ftp, ethernet

Have an Asus ROG laptop (GL752VW) with, as usual, Wifi and ethernet.
Connecting to a(ny) ftp server fails when the ethernet NIC (Realtek PCIe GBE family) is enabled but succeeds when it is disabled using Wifi. The laptop runs latest W10, but this problem appears to be hardware related, however implausible that seems. Using ethernet I have normal browsing (Chrome) and peer to peer connectivity. I have no other reason to think that the realtek NIC is faulty, except that it does not connect at gigabyte speed - it's a lame duck.
Does anyone have an idea about potential FTP specific hardware failings or settings at the adapter level which may matter to FTP specifically?
Thanks,
Jan

Comment: Why does not it support gigabyte speeds.  I assume it’s a 10/100/1000 port

Comment: @Ramhound. You assume correctly, but the thing cannot be brought to 1000. Tested really exhaustively with wires and realtek ethernet diagnostic utility. Considered sending the backup in for replacement, but need it too much. Replacing it myself? someday, MAYBE. not easy. Probably a usb nic is a better option.

Answer (score 1):

I confess that I do not adhere to your suspicion concerning a possible hardware problem. Please note that the WiFi connection is different from the one via Ethernet. Different firewall rules apply. Please verify these rules on your laptop and on the router you are using.

Please note that there exists a so called passive mode on FTP. If disabled, the FTP protocol use two different TCP ports. Considering the operating procedure of many NAT routers, they often open only one of these TCP ports when using FTP. When the passive mode is enabled, only one port is used. This can resolve such blocking problems.

Comment: @Jan I agree with Claude. This is more likely to be that your NAT gateway isn’t handling FTP correctly on its Ethernet LAN ports, but it’s doing the right thing on its Wi-Fi AP interface.

Comment: @Claude & Spiff
Thank you for your suggestions.
I have a desktop connected to the same router (aside from the laptop) using ethernet only, FTP works on that machine. So the router or NAT gateway do not appear to be the cause. The laptop uses the same type realtek ethernet NIC as the laptop. I even put the desktop ethernet cable into the laptop, no result.

Comment: Gateway options: FTP and TFTP enable. No IP, MAC or Port filtering. Firewall of router: setting is medium. All the usual stuff like HTTP, not FTP specifically. FTP-S on ports 989-990 TCP.

Comment: Even if you use different ports on the same router, the firewall rules can be different because they are related to the ports. In regard to the additional information you have supplied about he desktop, I think that the problem is located on your laptop. Probably local firewall rules or a software acting in a similar manner. Please verify carefully.

Comment: I ignore which software you are using for FTP. In order to debug your current situation, I suggest to use a simple FTP client program. Perhaps, the old, traditional one. There is a debug mode and a switch for active/passive mode. This could help you to find where the problem is located.

Comment: I installed the USB ethernet, some trouble to get it working, it had MAC 0. Anyway, it won't connect to ftp either. Tried to ping, no result, then used tracert on my desktop and pinged from laptop the hubs one by one. Stopped at gateway. So this puts the problem at the gateway and I am no longer looking for a hardware issue.

Comment: @Claude: Windows explorer and a C++ I wrote which is tasked to monitor an FTP directory and take action. So I know what I get back from LastError(), which is not informative (effectively connection could not be established). I'm now pinging away to locate the problem. So far it appears to be the gateway, but I could not find which settings block the ftp thru ethernet, and not through Wifi.

Comment: Setting Router/gateway IPv4 firewall protection to 'low' solves the problem. So I need to find whether I can allow ports individually, but basically, problem solved.
Thanks for your efforts and excuses for going off in the wrong direction.

Comment: Looks like I will have to use port forwarding to a static IP address. I am baffled why my W7 desktop does not have this problem. No forwarding in use for the desktop. Setting router firewall protection to high does not stop the desktop either. So finally, only the switch is left. A switch-less connection to the router has no problem, but a switched connection has.

Comment: I confess that I cannot consider a general and global reduction of protection as a solution. Considering your observations, I still suspect that you are trying to open a FTP session in active mode and that your NAT router does not open the necessary FTP data transport port after the FTP negotiation on the TCP control port 21 has negotiated this port. In fact, that is a common problem when using NAT routers, so that the passive FTP mode can be considered as a necessity in an environment using NAT routers. You will find a good explanation on Wikipedia when asking for "FTP protocol".